# Permission denied: couldn’t grab the accept mutex

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I have just configured a new server that keeps dying from time to time.
The error log indicated the following problem:

```
[Thu Feb 11 03:21:15.261690 2016] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1273] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Thu Feb 11 03:21:15.640431 2016] [core:alert] [pid 1256] AH00050: Child 1258 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
```

I tried the solution listed [here](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=411) (basically to add `AcceptMutex flock` to httpd.conf) , but Apache wouldn't start:

```
Invalid command 'AcceptMutex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
```

So now I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go back and look at the page you linked to, there's a line a little bit further down that says:

> With apache 2.4, use Mutex instead of AcceptMutex

Comment: Well...I feel so stupid.

Comment: @carla Been there, done that...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
AcceptMutex posixsem
```

in your apache conf

Comment: Yes, I tried, and the same "Invalid Command" message appeared when I tried to restart Apache.

Comment: @carla if you use apache 2.4 `Mutex posixsem`