# Permission denied: AH02478: failed to create proxy mutex

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, centos7, httpd, selinux

Running a local centos 7 apache webserver, recently it stopped working. Journalctl don't say anything other then service failed. Only the error_log in `/var/log/httpd/` says:

```
[core:notice] [pid 5026:tid 139693344536768] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[suexec:notice] [pid 5026:tid 139693344536768] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[core:emerg] [pid 5026:tid 139693344536768] (13)Permission denied: AH00023: Couldn't create the proxy mutex 
[proxy:crit] [pid 5026:tid 139693344536768] (13)Permission denied: AH02478: failed to create proxy mutex
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

However I can't figure out what file is meant nor find on the internet anything to this one.

Comment: Funny enough starting through `/user/sbin/httpd` works fine... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay thanks to [Permission denied: couldn’t grab the accept mutex](https://serverfault.com/questions/755823/permission-denied-couldn-t-grab-the-accept-mutex) I added following to my httpd.conf:

```
Mutex posixsem
```

Which did fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles onto this, I'm able to reproduce the issue by running an apache2 docker container on a non-native platform via qemu emulation.

If you're seeing the issue from a Docker image, try changing the platform to match the host system.